# Output argument not assigned during call: MATLAB Error

Tags: matlab, function

This is my function.

```
function [ phi, lambda, h ] = trans_cartesian( x, y, z )
    a=6378137; 
    b=6356752.3141;
    e2=(a^2-b^2)/(a^2);
    lambda= atand(y/x);
    P= sqrt(x^2+y^2); 


    phi=atand((z/P)/(1-(e2)));
    while phi< 10^-12;   
        N= a/sqrt(1-(e2).*(sind(phi))^2);
        h= (P/cosd(phi))-N;
        phi=atand((z/P)/(1-(N/N+h).*(e2)));    
   end
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
This is the actual error message:

> Output argument "h" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "C:\trans_cartesian.m>trans_cartesian".

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your error, in some situation the condition of `while` loop is not true. And your code must be return the value of `h`. So, you should set a initial value for `h` at least in your code. For example:

```
function [ phi, lambda, h ] = trans_cartesian( x, y, z )
h = 0
% continue
```

Or, put a condition after the `while` if the condition of loop is not correct, replace the value of `h` into the particular value:

```
function [ phi, lambda, h ] = trans_cartesian( x, y, z )
%your code 
while phi<10^-12
    % your code
end
if(phi > 10^-12)
    h = 0; % or specified value
end
```